# Creating subfolders in specific, multiple parent folders

Tags: powershell, directory, directory-structure

Our current folder structure is \server\Usr\All Clients\Current\client_name with multiple folders under each client (consulting, financials, payroll, permanent, tax).

I need to create subfolders called 2017 and 2018 in just financials, payroll, and tax.

There are over 2000 clients, so I'd like to use a PowerShell script to do it.  I found the following example, but it creates the 2017 subfolders in all folders under financials.

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem '\\server\Usr\All Clients\Current\*\Financials' -Directory))
{
     new-item -ItemType directory -Path ($folder.fullname+"\2017")
}
```

How can I have it only create 2017 in specific folders?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array to store the directories in which to create 2017 and 2018.

```
$ParentDirectories = @("Financials", "Payroll", "Tax")
```

And then, filter the folders with the array creating sub-directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\server\Usr\All Clients\Current\' | ForEach-Object {
    $Client = $_.Name;

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Client | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $ParentDirectories } | ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory @("$Client\$_\2017", "$Client\$_\2018")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Edit: Tested and works !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just stack some ForEach:

```
ForEach ($Client in (Get-ChildItem "\\server\Usr\All Clients\Current\*" -Directory)){
  ForEach ($Depth in 'Financials','Payroll','Tax') {
    ForEach ($Year in '2017','2018') {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ("{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $($Client.fullname),$Depth,$Year ) -Whatif
    }
  }
}
```

If the output looks OK , remove the `-WhatIf`

```
Sample run on my Ramdrive A: with pseudo clients Baker,Miller,Smith:

> tree
A:.
├───Baker
│   ├───Financials
│   │   ├───2017
│   │   └───2018
│   ├───Payroll
│   │   ├───2017
│   │   └───2018
│   └───Tax
│       ├───2017
│       └───2018
├───Miller
│   ├───Financials
...
└───Smith
    ├───Financials
    │   ├───2017
    │   └───2018
    ├───Payroll
    │   ├───2017
    │   └───2018
    └───Tax
        ├───2017
        └───2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a where object to select the folders that you want to create the folder in

```
# Get folders that are Financials, Payrol, or Tax
$Folders = Get-ChildItem '\\server\Usr\All Clients\Current\*' | Where-Object -Property Name -in -Value 'Financials','Payroll','Tax'

# Loop through those folders
foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $2017Path = Join-Path -Path $Folder.FullName -ChildPath '2017' # Generate path to 2017 folder
    $2018Path = Join-Path -Path $Folder.FullName -ChildPath '2018' # Generate path to 2018 folder
    New-Item -Path $2017Path -Force # Create 2017 folder
    New-Item -Path $2018Path -Force # Create 2018 folder
}
```

Use `New-Item -WhatIf` if you want to see output of where the folders are being created. I am unable to completely test as I have no access to your specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's untested but if it doesn't work 100%, it'll get you REALLY close.

```
#requires -Version 5
$createFolders = '2017','2018'

@(Get-ChildItem -Path '\\server\Usr\All Clients\Current' -Recurse -Directory -Depth 1).where({ $_.Name -in 'financials','payroll','tax' }).foreach({ 
    $clientFolder = $_.FullName;  
    $createFolders | foreach { 
        $null = mkdir -Path "$clientFolder\$_" 
    }
})
```

Comment: Great! Could you mark it as answered? Not sure why I'm downvoted when I helped fix your problem but oh well. :)